# Filepath to xml within xlsx in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, saxon, xlsx

I'm doing an xslt transform of the xml within an excel file using Saxon where the transform is being done on the .rels xml file within the xlsx file. I currently have a workaround in place where I have unzipped the entire contents of the xlsx file into a seperate folder. However, for simplicity's sake my program takes the xlsx file as it's input, so I was wondering if there was a simpler way for my program to point to the xml within the xlsx file without the need to unzip the contents. I've tried pathing to file.xlsx\_rels\.rels but that doesn't seem to work. The code I'm current using for this input is

```
String inputFile = "file.xlsx_folder\\_rels\\.rels"
XdmNode input = processor.NewDocumentBuilder().Build(new Uri(inputFile));
```

but I would like to have that point directly within the xlsx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a simpler way, you don't need to unzip the whole file.

Instead of the file path you've passed as a parameter to the Saxon APIs Build function, pass an XmlReader or Stream instance of the uncompressed part of the xslx file.

The Open static method of [System.IO.Packaging.Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.package.aspx) can be used to get a Package instance on which you call GetStream to uncompress the part you need and return it as a Stream. Package handles files conforming to the Open Packaging Convention, like Excel's xslx format.

The code below uncompresses the package part to a Stream, uses this to create an XmlReader instance, and finally passes the XmlReader as the parameter to the Build function:

```
            string filename = "c:\\test\\file.xslx";
            string partPath = "/_rels/.rels";

            Package xpsPackage = Package.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open)
            Uri partUri = new Uri(partPath, UriKind.Relative);
            PackagePart xpsPart = xpsPackage.GetPart(partUri);

            Stream xpsStream = xpsPart.GetStream(FileMode.Open)
            XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(xpsStream);

            XdmNode input = processor.NewDocumentBuilder().Build(xmlReader);
```